# Xml linq query based on 2 Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I return all the "Title" values for a particular 'Author' using linq ?

```
<Details xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Record>
    <Author>Barry White</Author>
    <Title>First Book</Title>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Author>Barry White</Author>
    <Title>Second Book</Title>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Author>Norman White</Author>
    <Title>Second Book</Title>
  </Record>
 </Details>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

var author = "Barry White";
var titles = (from r in xDoc.Root.Elements("Record")
              let _author = (string)r.Element("Author")
              let _title = (string)r.Element("Title")
              where _author == author
              select _title).ToList();
```

or using method-based query:

```
var titles = xDoc.Root.Elements("Record")
                 .Where(r => (string)r.Element("Author") == author)
                 .Select(r => (string)r.Element("Title"))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.xml.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var titles = XDocument.Parse(inputxml)
                      .Descendants("Record")
                      .Where(x => x.Element("Author").Value == "Barry White")
                      .Select(x => x.Element("Title").Value)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Descendants` like that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because it makes the query less efficient

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, if I know XML structure well and I'm sure there is only one `Record` tag usage, why not?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Premature optimization, yada yada.

Comment: Well, that's your opinion. I don't think it's premature. You don't know how big the original file is, do you? It may not matter when you have 3 records, but with bigger file it gives you a lot of unnecessary checks.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek have you done or read any comparison between `Descendants` and `Elements` for, for example, 100 MB XML file?

Comment: @KonradKokosa `Descendants` is ~25% slower with 1% matched `<author>` elements value. Tested with ~80MB file size. For 0.001% author names matched ratio goes to ~30%

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek quite an edge cases but I will remember about it, thanks